# Spans next to each other have the same height

Tags: html

There are spans:

```
<span style="width: 25%; float:left;">A</span><span style="width: 75%; float:left;">B</span>
```

Now if column A or B have different heights, this all falls apart. If A has 40px height, I want B to have the same height. To be auto expanded heights, in other words. How is it possible?

Comment: How are you setting the heights atm? Just based on the content?

Comment: just based on the content yes

Comment: Would it help if you put span B in span A?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
    <span style="height: 100%; width: 25%; float:left;">A</span><span style="height: 100%; width: 75%; float:left;">B</span>
</div>
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Thats ok, but the height is defined by column A or B, it cant be fixed.

Comment: if content A is too long, it needs 2 lines so this increase the height

Answer (score 1):

I think you should sorround the span with a contanier `div` and use the [One True Layout trick of Equal Height Columns](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/equalheight) to ensure the two spans have the same height.

You also need to use the `word-wrap: break-word;` property in both `span`.

It's better to see it in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y7TDQ/1/